# Android Webservice

Tags: android, web-services

HI

i am new to android. i want to use ksoap2 to connect to web service.Can anyone give me links to a good sample application code.

it will be of great help to me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using kSoap2 is really best thing when your getting SOAP response.

Here are links which can help you to use kSoap2:-

1. [Overview About It.](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=LC2NCXXTTONGRQE1GHPCKHWATMY32JVN?articleId=208800166&dept_url=/mobility/)
2. [About using kSoap2](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)
3. [Receiving Response as Complex Type.](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html)

Please visit codereview.stackexchange.com thread of mine where I placed the code using kSoap2 [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/943/how-to-increase-download-speed-using-following-method-please-review)