# Calling WebMethod from android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json

I have used the code from this answer [Android services with RestFull web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199494/android-services-with-restfull-web-services)

but when I try to call like this,

```
json = restClientService.getResponseAsJSON("http://192.168.2.242/Test.aspx/Hello", params);
```

my asp.net web pages webmethod doesn't get fired. I added Page_Load code looks working but I want to be able to call WebMethods rather then page itself.

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(new { Hi = "Mr" });
        Response.End();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public object Hello()
    {
        return new { Hi = "Mr" };
    }
}
```

Comment: is ur webservice working on broswer?

Comment: you mean webmethod? no I doesn't work either

Comment: u r running on localhost or remote?

Comment: running on local iis, but debbugging on vs 2013. page is working just method is not.

Comment: I can reach json via pageload on android. just I couldn't manage to call webmethod.